# Alternate locations for javax.comm.properties in Windows

Tags: java, windows, serial-port, javax.comm

I'm building a program that needs to be installed on Windows machines for which I do not have write access to %JAVA_HOME%/lib.

Is there anywhere else I can move javax.comm.properties to other than %JAVA_HOME%/lib?

According to the Java COM API FAQ:

> Q: My application does not find any ports when it enumerates available
>   ports.
>   A: In order for the Java communications API to find ports the file
>   javax.comm.properties must be in the correct place. The preferred
>   location is in /lib. See the installation instructions for
>   alternate locations and further information.

Where can I find the Sun installation instructions that contain these alternate locations?

Answer (score 0):

Base on things that a guy said over here:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1316406

You can put the file *javax.comm.properties* where you have laid **comm.jar**. But then to run the program, you should specify the path which points to comm.jar like this:

```
java -cp <your.class.path>;<path.to>/comm.jar YourProgramThatUsesComm.jar
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: When I try that I get a NoClassDefFoundError for javax/comm/NoSuchPortException. The only way I can get the program to run, but with no COM ports showing up, is by putting the comm.jar inside MyProgram.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works for me. Here are the requirements:

- `comm.jar` must be named exactly `comm.jar` (not `comm-2.0.jar` for example), and must be located in the classpath in a directory named exactly `"lib"`.
- `javax.comm.properties` must also have that exact name, and be located in the same directory as `comm.jar`.
- `win32com.dll` must be referenced in the `java.library.path`.

So, if you have a directory setup like this:

```
- lib\
   |- comm.jar
   |- javax.comm.properties
- ext\
   |- win32com.dll
```

Then you can use the following `java` command while in the root of these directories (assuming your project's `jar` file with `YourMainClass` is also in the `lib` directory:

```
java -Djava.library.path=.\ext -cp .\lib\* YourMainClass
```

With this, you should no longer need to put anything under the `\bin` or `\lib` directories of your JRE.